# Toggling IK on and off will change the bone's transform position slightly

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

As stated in the topic, whenever I turn on/off the IK bones, their positions drift a little bit. And I cankeep changing their positions by keep turning them on/off.
[image]

Why is this happening? And how do I make sure it doens't happen again?

Thanks a lot in advance!